# is it possible to reload the embed content from TikTok after loading a page?

Tags: javascript, instagram, embed

On my SPA app for instagram I use this code:

```
window.instgrm.Embeds.process()
```

Comment: ```getElementById('yourFrame').contentDocument.location.reload()```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming here after all these years wondering I solved it like this

```js
const tiktoksOnPage = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('blockquote.tiktok-embed'),
);
if (typeof tiktokEmbed !== 'undefined' && tiktoksOnPage.length) {
  tiktokEmbed.lib.render(tiktoksOnPage);
}
```

You need to embed the script of course

Comment: Did you have any CORS issues? headers you needed to set? Your solution is awesome but only works for me in an insecure browser (Chrome launched with `--disable-web-security`, otherwise the tiktok lib requests just hang (stay in 'pending' state indefinitely).